# Django allauth activation code during registration

Tags: django, django-allauth, activation

I am using Django allauth for authentication to my rest api. I have the whole process working as expected (login, registration, password reset) with email confirmation ..etc.

My question is when a user register the user receives an email with the link that user need to click and confirm to get access to the website. However, i want to use allauth but instead of a link I want a randomly generated activation code (example: 123456). That user can input in a form to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Allauth currently doesn't support this. You could open up an issue asking for the feature to be implemented, but considering that there's really no obvious advantage of using both systems, I doubt this would be accepted.

Is there a reason why the link method doesn't work for you, but this does? If so, maybe there's some workaround that could work?

Here's a possible workaround (albeit a very complicated one):

1. Write a template tag that would trim out the website part (ex example.com/confirm/ out of example.com/confirm/sdafsdagfsagfsdafasdfsafgfdsg), so that only the actual code is sent to the user in the email
2. Make a form that would accept this code, and, on submission, reconstruct the url back to its original state, and go to that url, effectively activating the account. You would almost definitely need to write custom javascript for this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need this as our django is a backend to a mobile app and it looks like all new apps that i use follow this method. The possible workaround looks really complicated.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but for me, the exact method used isn't as important. Maybe use allauth's system, but then have the landing webpage direct the browser to try to open the app?